# Error of Installing dlib in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, dlib

I'm trying to install Dlib in anaconda python with this line:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib
```

and I'm getting error like this:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - dlib
  - xlwt
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add more information about the Python/Anaconda version?

Answer (score 0):

Path of core-meta: `C/users/{xxx}/anaconda3/core-meta`

Delete core-meta then run the following commands:

1. `Conda update --all`
2. `Conda install dlib`

These commands require an internet connection so keep wifi on during the command running process.

Here `xxx` is the username on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the xlwt-package for your project, just create a new conda environment and install the dlip package locally in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try following:

```
brew install cmake
brew install boost
```

then create a virtual environment using conda command

`conda create -n dlib python=3.6 anaconda`

Activate the environment

`source activate dlib`

run the following command

`conda install pip`

and finally install dlib using below command

`pip install dlib`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anaconda or miniconda3, please see the following installation procedures. It will comply with Python 3.7 in this way.

**1.Install cmake with git**

```
$ sudo apt-get install git cmake
```

**2. Enter into the the directory**

Please change user to your own username

```
$ cd /home/user/dlib
```

**3. Compile dlib**

```
$ python setup.py install
```

If meeting with the issue that you could not put the import statements of setuptools behind the import statement of distutils, please change the placement oder in setup.py in the directory of dlib.

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

from distutils import log
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
```

**4. Run the dlib unit test suite in the current working directory**

Please note there is a sub-directory of dlib inlcuded in the directory of dlib.

```
$ cd dlib/test
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ cmake --build . --config Release
$./dtest --runall
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Install dlib for windows 11

Requirements:
Install cmake(while installing tick add to path option),
Visual Studio 2022(after installing make sure desktop development for C++ is ticked )

I tried installing dlib using pip install dlib in windows powershell/bash/command prompt but it was showing some error.

My solution(which worked for Windows 11 and python 3.11.2):

1. Install Anaconda
2. Open anaconda terminal
3. Create an environment

   ```
   conda create --name myenv
   ```

(where myeve is your environment name)

4. Activate your environment

   ```
   conda activate myenv
   ```
5. After activating you can install your pakages using conda commands, for installing dlib type

   ```
    conda install -c conda-forge dlib
   ```

Your dlib is installed

While running your code make sure of the following points:

1. You have selected the correct conda python interpreter where your dlib is installed
2. you have to activate the environment in the terminal(anaconda/cmd/powershell) else it will show 'dlib module not found error'
3. After activating the environment go to your project folder and run your python file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it worked for me:-

```
pip install dlib -vvv
```

Answer (score -1):

on mac system :
you have to do it via brew

1. brew install cmake
2. brew install boost
3. brew install boost-python --with-python3

After installing above packages if you need you can create your environment and proceed with dlib installation or you can simply run next step.

The dlib library doesn’t have any real Python prerequisites, but if you plan on using dlib for any type of computer vision or image processing, These are few libraries which you can install for dlib :

```
* NumPy
* SciPy
* scikit-image
```

4. pip install numpy

5 pip install Scipy

6. pip install scikit-image
7. pip install dlib

you can check for more details on this link:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/

Answer (score -2):

You have to try by putting just:

```
conda install dlib
```

Comment: `conda install -c menpo dlib` is fine.